# Как правильно вставить строку кода в код php?

Tags: php

Подскажите плиз, куда правильно в этот код, который ниже, вставить target="blank" и rel="nofollow", чтобы при клике на кнопку сайт открывался в новом окне.

```
<?php
if(isset(get_post_meta(get_the_ID())['referal'][0]) && get_post_meta(get_the_ID())['referal'][0] !== ""){ ?>
<a href = "<?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID())['referal'][0]; ?>">
<button class="shop">Перейти в магазин</button></a>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Эло же аттрибуты тега `<a>`, вот и добавьте ему. PHP-код строгать не нужно:

```
<?php
if(isset(get_post_meta(get_the_ID())['referal'][0]) && get_post_meta(get_the_ID())['referal'][0] !== ""){ ?>
<a target="_blank" rel="nofollow" href="<?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID())['referal'][0]; ?>">
    <button class="shop">Перейти в магазин</button>
</a>
<?php } ?>
```

Обратите внимание: правильно `target="_blank"`

Comment: спасибо, буду знать!